# Wide space between label for vertical radio button and first choice

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Wide space between label for vertical radio button and first choice.  In an ideal world, I would love it to be the same amount of space as between the field labels and the top line on the fields.  Any thoughts or ideas?  Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/steveadams617/MgcDU/8543/

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label for="provider_id">Provider</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" name="provider_id_auto" id="provider_id_auto"/>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label for='phone_us'>Phone</label>
                <input class='form-control phone_us' type='text' maxlength='14' value='' name='phone_us' id='phone_us'/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .row -->

    <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="med_coverage_id">Insurance Coverage</label>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="med_coverage_id" value="1" checked />
                        Pending
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="med_coverage_id" value="2"    />
                        Covered
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="med_coverage_id" value="3"    />
                        Needs Prior Approval
                    </label>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .row -->
    </form>
</div><!-- .container -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div .radio has a margin-top of 10px. You can manually adjust this like so

```
<div class="radio" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="med_coverage_id" value="1" checked="">Pending </label>
</div>
```

or of course edit the stylesheet or add your own style to the .radio-class (eg if you are using a CDN).